# Bound on the distance between two elements of the Hilbert cube

Tags: real-analysis

I am studying for my PhD qualifying exams by going through all of the problems in Carother's real analysis. I came across this problem:

The Hilbert cube is the collection of all real sequences $x = (x_n)$ with $\lvert x_n \rvert \leq 1$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $d(x, y) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}\lvert x_n - y_n \rvert$. Given x and y in the Hilbert cube and $k \in \mathbb{N}$, let $M_k = max\{\lvert x_1 - y_1 \rvert...\lvert x_k - y_k \rvert\}$. Show that $d(x, y) \leq M_k + 2^{-k}$

This is what I have:

$$d(x,y) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}\lvert x_n - y_n \rvert \leq \sum_{n=1}^{k}2^{-n}M_k + \sum_{n=k+1}^{\infty}2^{-n+1} = M_k - M_k2^{-k} + 2^{-k} < M_k + 2^{-k}$$

If my work is correct the inequality is strict. How could the distance between two sequences in the Hilbert cube equal $M_k + 2^{-k}$?

Comment: it can't,,,,,,,

Comment: Ok I thought so